# using ubuntu crontab for postgres 9.1.4, I want to use crontab to delete rows in a local postgres database table every 30 minutes on the same server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cron

using ubuntu crontab for postgres 9.1.4, I want to use crontab to delete rows in a local postgres database  table every 30 minutes on the same server.
eg on server 10.10.10.123

I have Postres 9.1.4 running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS . I have a local database installed, and I  want to be able to delete rows in that database every 30 minutes.

thereofer delete from mybetablename; to run every 30 mitues from crontab

I have the username and password of the user

please help

I tried writing a script that can access postgresql and didnt work

Comment: On command line, try this first: `PGPASSWORD="yourpassword" psql --user=youruser --dbname=yourDB --command="delete from expmybetablename"`. If that works, you can write in cron `0, 30 * * * * PGPASSWORD="yourpassword" psql --user=youruser --dbname=yourDB --command="delete from mybetablename"`. WARNING: Your password will be visible to anyone who has access to that cron table. Also, if you are deleting all data from that table, you could use `truncate table mybetablename` instead of `delete from mybetablename`.

Comment: Take a look at [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) and [pg_timetable](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_timetable). They run cron like jobs into the database.